# Response.Redirect with querystring only working the first time

Tags: asp.net

I have a production system which has a button to go a quoting system on a different site. The button calls

```
Response.Redirect("https://www.???????.com/program/EditQuote.aspx?QuoteNumber=" & Trim(txtQuoteNum.Text), False)
```

It works perfectly the first time, but after that (if I close the tab that opened) the target page comes up with almost all the data missing from the page which should have been loaded in the page_load event of that page. Here is the code in the page_load event

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
   If Request.QueryString("QuoteNumber") IsNot Nothing AndAlso IsNumeric(Request.QueryString("QuoteNumber")) Then
      Session("LoadQuoteNumber") = Request.QueryString("QuoteNumber")
   End If
End If
```

The only way it works again is if I close the browser and start again. It works on my dev machine on localhost so I don't know how to try to follow what's going on to debug this type of problem which only happens in the production environment.

Comment: Initially it sounds like a problem with session on your production system. How is session stored on that server?

Comment: How would I know? It's IIS 7.

Comment: Here is a blog I found real quick that talks about each type of state server setting and how to change them. http://dotnetvault.blogspot.com/2008/07/configuring-session-state-settings-for.html. If you are using InProc, the session data is stored in the memory of the application pool process, so if the app pool resets, you lose the contents of session. Any application pool resets will be logged in the System section of the event log. Take a look there to see if your app pool is reseting.

Comment: I did try making the system response.write all session variables to see if that was the problem and they were all intact. Does that tell us that the session was okay?

Comment: I just checked the server event log and there was nothing there when this happens.

Comment: Add the code that loads the data into the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following code which was in the code behind:

```
Private _refreshState As Boolean
Private _isRefresh As Boolean

Protected Overrides Sub LoadViewState(ByVal savedState As Object)
    Dim AllStates As Object() = savedState
    MyBase.LoadViewState(AllStates(0))
    _refreshState = Boolean.Parse(AllStates(1))
    _isRefresh = _refreshState = Session("__ISREFRESH")
End Sub

Protected Overrides Function SaveViewState() As Object
    Session("__ISREFRESH") = _refreshState
    Dim AllStates() As Object = New Object(2) {}
    AllStates(0) = MyBase.SaveViewState
    AllStates(1) = Not (_refreshState)
    Return AllStates
End Function
```

It was put in to solve a problem we had when the user refreshed the page. Here's the article which gave is the code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10240/Detecting-Page-Refresh